# How To Center Child Divs In Flex Parent Div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I have an html page called presets page. This page contains different (child) divs and I am having a hard time on how I could center all these divs within the container (parent) div. These preset divs are currently in flexbox. Apologies if this question has been answered already, I really suck in centering elements in html/css.

It currently looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlvlB.png).

And I want it to look somewhat like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm56h.png).

**I tried using `justify-content: center` but how can I make the last line align to the left/right to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD3VB.png)?**

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="presets-container">
  {% for presets in presets_list %}
  <div class="preset">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" id="header">
        <div class="col-7">
          <h1>{{ presets.preset_name|hide_preset_suffix }}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
          <div class="options">
              <div style="cursor:pointer;" class="button pr_edit" id="{{ 'load,'|create_id:forloop.counter }}" onclick="loadPreset(this.id)">LOAD</div>
              <div style="cursor:pointer;" class="button pr_edit" id="{{ 'delete,'|create_id:forloop.counter }}" onclick="deletePreset(this.id)">DELETE</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Here is the CSS for the presets container:

```
.presets-container{
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: please add your code to question

Comment: To center horizontally `justify-content: center` and vertically `align-items: center`, Default value for `flex-direction` is `row` so you don't need to specify

Comment: Hello, After seeing your screenshot your requirement is to add equal margins around the content so use `justify-content: space-around`

Answer (score 4):

Add `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center` to the parent div

```css
.presets-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: pink;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `justify-content: center`

Comment: How do I make the last line align to the left and not make it center? Check last edit :)

Comment: Unfortunately that's an unsolved problem ;-) , i.e. not easily possible. You'd have to use a container within the container which is only wide enough for the three columns and which you center inside its parent (using the default `justify-content: flex-start`) inside it - usually rather too complicated...

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `div` under `presets-container` and then use `justify-content: center` in `presets-container`